# Emacs auto-complete.el switch tab to spacebar

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I've used auto-complete.el in Emacs for ages.  I'm using Emacs a bit more these days and my left pinky is starting to get RSI from hitting TAB and ctrl all the time.  I've done some keyboard remapping to alleviate the situation but every few characters I'm generally pressing tab to complete a word.  Is there any way to switch auto-complete.el from using TAB for completion to spacebar with my less used and stronger thumbs?

**Edit2**: I was using a really old version of auto-complete.el which meant that @hd1 suggestion didn't work for me immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to the [source](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/auto-complete.el) and scrolling down to line 235 shows that if you set the variable `ac-trigger-key` you can change the key that's used to trigger completion. You should set this variable in your `custom-set-variables` block in your .emacs file.

Comment: Do I have a different version of auto-complete.el than you?  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/auto-complete.el  In my file line 235 is still in the comments.  I've had a dig around inside the file and maybe I'm close to a solution: (define-key ac-complete-mode-map "SPC" 'ac-complete)  However this stops auto completion and inserts a space.  Putting something else instead of "SPC", e.g. "\C-h" or just "h" works.  It appears there's something special about the space character preventing this behaviour.

Comment: At the moment I've got (define-key ac-complete-mode-map "6" 'ac-complete) in my .emacs.  It's a dreadful hack but don't often complete things with numbers in them!

Comment: Ah, the top Google search result for auto-complete.el takes you to a well out of date file...  Latest is here https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete

Comment: I did link to the one on github, @GilesRoberts

Comment: Sorry I missed the link you'd put in.  I'll download the new version tomorrow and have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think ac-complete-mode-map is a keymap used when the auto-complete
menu is shown. How about trying something like this instead (this is
my setting):

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-SPC") 'auto-complete)
```

If you don't use evil, you need to find another keymap. Perhaps a
mode-specific map, or even global-map will work.

Comment: The real issue I had was I was using a well out of date version of auto-complete.el.